# Layout in internet explorer is broken

Tags: html, wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

So i've been working on this website ( http://iulian.cablevision.ro/fc-botosani )and my layout in chrome and firefox seems to be ok. But when i open in Internet explorer 8 it's like a disaster... everything is messed up. Can't find why and how to fix this problem.

[image]

Comment: Just a side-note. Internet Explorer 8 isn't even supported by Microsoft itself anymore. I would skip it..

Comment: Well If I want to be a good developer I must learn more as I develop. It's more like a chalage to me. And I know a lot of people who still use Internet Explorer as a web browser. The elder people got used to it and won't want to upgrade to chrome or mozila. just like my father, lol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much details, we won't be able to help you. What did you try to do? Do you have an idea? You can use the site [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) to find the problem by entering a CSS property or HTML tag. First of all, look at your CSS to find the problematic rule.

Comment: The problem was with the @media property. It's not supported by IE8... that tool helped me a lot. thx

Comment: Cool! This tool is a must-have. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I've found one of the most useful things for sorting out Internet Explorer problems is running the site through the W3C Validator:

http://validator.w3.org/

Often just fixing whatever the validator says is wrong, even the simple stuff, corrects issues in IE.  Good luck!

Comment: The problem was with the @media property, it's not suported in IE8